# React JSX: href path inside an array of anchor tags is referencing the last path in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to generate an array of anchor tags each with different href values. I am running into an issue where the path of each anchor tag  turns out to be the same as the path at the end of a for loop. How should I modify my code so that the paths are not all referencing the last value of path in the loop?

Here is my code:

```
  function generateLinks(){
    let path = '/';
    let links = [ <a href={ path }>root</a> ];
    for (let link = 0; link < 5; link++){
      const partial =  "folder"+ link;
      path += partial + '/'
      links.push(<a href={ path }>{ partial }</a>);
    }
   return links;
 }
```

Currently this outputs:

[`<a href='/folder0/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/'>root</a>`, `<a href='/folder0/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/'>folder0</a>`,`<a href='/folder0/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/'>folder1</a>`,`<a href='/folder0/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/'>folder2</a>`,`<a href='/folder0/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/'>folder3</a>`,`<a href='/folder0/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/'>folder4</a>`]

My desired output is:

[`<a href='/'>root</a>`, `<a href='/folder0/'>folder0</a>`,`<a href='/folder0/folder1/'>folder1</a>`,`<a href='/folder0/folder1/folder2/'>folder2</a>`,`<a href='/folder0/folder1/folder2/folder3/'>folder3</a>`,`<a href='/folder0/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/'>folder4</a>`]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted works correctly.  Your real code must be different.  Here's a jsfiddle showing it has the correct href values: https://jsfiddle.net/8d2xLc9L/

```
 function generateLinks(){
    let path = '/';
    let links = [ <a href={ path }>root</a> ];
    for (let link = 0; link < 5; link++){
      const partial =  "folder"+ link;
      path += partial + '/'
      links.push(<a href={ path }>{ partial }</a>);
    }
   return links;
 }

 document.getElementById("container").textContent = JSON.stringify(generateLinks(), null, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's true, your logic works well!

Perhaps the way you loop the array in JSX has problem? The above one works work me:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class MyApp extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  generateLinks(){
    let path = '/';
    let links = [ <a href={ path }>root</a> ];
    for (let link = 0; link < 5; link++){
      const partial =  "folder"+ link;
      path += partial + '/'
      links.push(<a href={ path }>{ partial }</a>);
    }
    return links;
  }

  render(){
    return <div>{this.generateLinks()}</div>;
  }

}
```